# Python string.replace alternative

Tags: python, string

I need help with Python string manipulation (I boiled down my previous looong question to this issue below).

For this line from a file:

```
L20B, CVS=1, HTYP=16, MLV=25
```

The second field could be CVS or VS. Related data will be present till the end of the line.

Need to replace the part starting with CVS or VS with another string:

```
if CVS found, then replacement is CFIXD(0,1,0) -OR-
if VS found, then replacement is FIXD(0,1,0)
```

Examples:

```
old line: L20B, CVS=1, HTYP=16, MLV=25
new line: L20B, CFIXD(0,1,0)

Old line: T10, M312, P10, Z3710, CL=L1, RH=1  (here, identify RH only and replace with)
New line: T10, M312, P10, Z3710, CL=L1, FIXD(0,1,0)

Old line: T20, M312, P20, Z100, CKR=10000 DV(0,1,0) 
New line: T20, M312, P20, Z100, CLS(0,1,0), MU=0.35

So, the replacement string keeps changing with what is found.
CVS or VS (till end of line) is replaced with CFIXD(0,1,0) or FIXD(0,1,0)
CRH or RH (till end of line) is replaced with CVR(0,1,0) or VR(0,1,0)
CFIXD or FIXD (till end of line) is replaced with CVR(0,1,0) or VR(0,1,0)
20 other variants.

Also, is it possible to modify the re.sub() expression to identify something in the search string and carry it over to the replacement string?
For e.g., 
Search for CFIXD(x,y,z) - replace with CVR (x,y,z)
```

I cannot search for the exact substring ("CVS=1, HTYP=16, MLV=25") since the data after the CVS (or VS) could be many different variations like

```
CVS=2, HTYP=11, MLV=25 
VS=4, HTYP=9, MLV=5      etc.
```

The length as you can see could be different too. Only thing I know for sure is that the string starting with CVS or VS goes till the end of that line.  As far as I know, string.replace won't work because of the above varying length and data.

Any readily available Python methods? Or do I have to write a small routine to do this? I can find the index (using string.find) to the VS or CVS and then replace everything from that point to the end of the line, yes? I know there is a simple (not for me) regex way. Thanks.

Comment: Am I correct in understanding that you wish to grab everything after and including the characters "CVS=" or "VS="? It is not clear what needs to be replaced. Can you give example input and output strings? This should be a simple regex exercise.

Comment: just added examples to the main question area.

Answer (score 3):

Use regular expressions:

```
import re
re.sub(r'(C|)VS=.*', r'\1FIXD(0,1,0)', line)
```

Explanation:

```
# regex
  (C|)         # optionally match a 'C', save it or an empty string in group 1
  VS=          # match 'VS='
  .*           # match to the end of the line

# replacement
  \1           # the contents of group 1 (either 'C' or an empty string)
  FIXD(0,1,0)  # the literal string 'FIXD(0,1,0)'
```

Examples:

```
>>> re.sub(r'(C|)VS=.*', r'\1FIXD(0,1,0)', 'L20B, CVS=1, HTYP=16, MLV=25')
'L20B, CFIXD(0,1,0)'
>>> re.sub(r'(C|)VS=.*', r'\1FIXD(0,1,0)', 'L20C, VS=4, HTYP=9, MLV=5')
'L20C, FIXD(0,1,0)'
```

**Edit:** based on your edit here are a few alternatives for your different cases:

- CVS or VS -> CFIXD(0,1,0) or FIXD(0,1,0)

  ```
  re.sub(r'(C|)VS=.*', r'\1FIXD(0,1,0)', line)
  ```
- CRH or RH -> CVR(0,1,0) or VR(0,1,0)

  ```
  re.sub(r'(C|)RH=.*', r'\1VR(0,1,0)', line)
  ```
- CFIXD(x,y,z) or VIXD(x,y,z) -> CVR(x,y,z) or VR(x,y,z)

  ```
  re.sub(r'(C|)FIXD(\([^)]*\)).*', r'\1VR\2', line)
  ```

Explanation of `(\([^)]\)).*`:

```
(         # start second capture group
   \(       # match a literal '('
   [^)]*    # match any number of characters that are not ')'
   \)       # match a literal ')'
)         # end capture group
.*        # match to the end of the line
```

Comment: Thanks, that looks simple. But, will it add the 'C' if it finds it?

Comment: Yes, but it is probably better to use a solution that you understand.  If you have specific questions about how this works feel free to ask.

Comment: Actually, the last field (replacement) needs to be one of many choices. CVS/VS replace with FIXD() or CFIXD, RH/CRH replace with CLS()...... or LS()......., and so on. But, if I figure out the mechanism for one, I can handle the others.

Comment: Ahh got it, if you are having trouble adapting it to your other fields, you should be able to use `re.sub(r'(C|)RH=.*', r'\1LS(0,1,0)', line)` for the RH/CRH replacements.

Comment: Sorry, I just elaborated with more examples. Thank you kindly for assisting me.

Comment: Holy Moly, this regex can be magic. Thank you again for putting in your time. I will start trying out now. To understand, '(C|)' means optionally look for C and if found save in group 1. I see the allusion to a group 2 but cannot understand how (\([^)]*\)).* works. Also, how can I communicate to you if I post a comment on this issue in the future?

Comment: I just added explanation for that section of the regex, just comment here if you have more questions.

Comment: FJ, I think your soln. is working...but printing the changes via ("print >> filename, line") produces an extra line between lines. How do I stop it from adding that extra line. I will post the finished code when it is. Prob. another few minutes.

Comment: That is happening because each line ends with a line break, and `print` automatically appends a line break.  Use `f = open(filename, 'w')` to get a file object then use `f.write(line)`.  Alternatively you can remove the line break characters from the end of `line` using `line.rstrip(os.linesep)`.

Comment: Thanks, I will try that now. Should I post the finished code somewhere else or in the question section? Also, f.write() works. The rstrip version did not.

Comment: If you have additional questions, you should post what you currently have in a new question.  If you are satisfied with how things are now then there is no need to update your question with the final product.  For the rstrip version to work you would need to `import os` somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regular expression, but to me it'd be more straightforward to just split the string into a list:

```
line = "L20B, CVS=1, HTYP=16, MLV=25"

line = line.split(", ")
if line[1].startswith("CVS="):
    line[1:] = ["CFIXD(0,1,0)"]
elif line[1].startswith("VS="):
    line[1:] = ["FIXD(0,1,0)"]

line = ", ".join(line)
```

These two cases could be combined with some jiggery-pokery, since they are rather similar, but they seem perfectly readable this way.

Comment: I agree but the problem is that VS could show up towards the end of the line. Example: T10,M312,P10,Z3710,CL=L1, VS=1,HTYP=16,MLV=25; in this case, I guess I could modify with a loop, say line[i].startswith("VS="). Is that right?

Comment: Yes, although you're starting to get into "regex is easier" territory here.

Comment: I like your solution but it gets verbose quickly with the 20 variants I have. But, it is understandable to a non-regex person like me. I will see how it goes. Thank you both for your quick help.